# Subjunctive mood - what is the tense of the verb following a conjunction?

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, subjunctive-mood, dependent-clause

Which verb is correct?

> If the world were perfect, workers would wear respirators even when dust levels were/are low.

"If the world were perfect" is an impossible condition/situation, which makes it subjunctive, correct?

Does the subjunctive mood only refer to a verb or does it refer to an unreal/imaginary/impossible situation? Example:

> "If the world were perfect . . ."
>   vs. 
>   "In a perfect world . . ."

Comment: I'm trying to see what is *subjunctive* about any of that. It looks like a straightforward use of the conditional following an *if* clause, to me.

Comment: ***Neither*** of them is the subjunctive. You wouldn't say *"... even when the dust level were low"* in either of the sentences, and if this were the subjunctive, the verb would be unchanged in the singular.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The "subjunctive" part of my question was meant to refer to the beginning of the sentence. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer here in EL&U land (or if your thread gets "closed"), please consider re-asking the same question over in ELL land. Grammar related questions like yours are welcome over there! :)

Comment: @Peter: I know the question has been edited since your comment, but it still seems incorrect even in the context of the original text that had *If circumstances **were** ideal*. Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive), *The subjunctive mood is also used for statements that are contrary to fact, such as "If I **were** a giraffe..." (**subjunctive**), as distinguished from "I was a child".*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, the first *were* is subjunctive. It looked clear to me at the time that the OP was talking about the second *were*, which wasn't in either of his constructions. That's the verb I meant.

Comment: @Peter: I don't really understand exactly what *subjunctive* means anyway. It might be a bit dated, but *if it **be** true* sounds just as "subjunctivey" to me as *if it **were** true*.

Answer (score 1):

The "dust levels are low" is a standing condition or statement of fact at an unknown future time.

"Ideally, workers would wear respirators even when dust levels are low."

Comment: How is this future? What it means is: *Even when the dust levels are low, workers should ideally wear respirators.* It encompasses all times, not just future.

Comment: Yes, it is meant to encompass all times. However, I need to use "would" instead of "should", because I'm expressing a state of being, rather than suggesting a change.

Answer (score 1):

A simple *[second conditional](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm)* without the third clause would be very easy to construct:

> *If the world were perfect, workers would wear respirators.*

The third clause, without the conditional, would also be very easy to construct:

> *Workers wear respirators even when dust levels **are** low.*

Ambiguity arises in combining the two constructions. Should the third clause reflect the:

> - subjunctive mood of the hypothetical unreal condition:
>
> *If the world were perfect ... even **if** dust levels **were** low*?
>
> **or** the
>
> - indicative mood of its internal reality:
>
> *even when dust levels **are** low?*

---

To stay out of past time, the hypothetical unreal condition: *If the world were perfect*, requires a *second conditional* construction. That settles the construction of the main clause:

> *If the world were perfect, workers would wear respirators...*

---

Since the main clause **is**: *workers would wear respirators*, compare the two options for the third clause:

> *workers would wear respirators even **if** dust levels **were** low.*

Notice *when* has been adjusted to *if*. This statement **correctly** explores a hypothetical action (*wear respirators*) conditional to a hypothetical situation (subjunctive: levels **were** low). So the entire sentence is hypothetical as implied by the **subjunctive** mood:

> *If the world **were** perfect, workers would wear respirators even **if** dust levels **were** low.*

---

The second option:

> *workers would wear respirators even when dust levels **are** low.*

This statement correctly explores a hypothetical action (*wear respirators*) related to a **real** situation (*indicative: levels **are** low*) in time (*when*). The hypothetical main clause is correctly conditional to one hypothetical unreal clause and modified by one indicative clause:

> *If the world **were** perfect, workers would wear respirators even when dust levels **are** low.*

---

**Conclusion:**

With the appropriate adjustment, both of the options for the third clause are grammatically correct **explorations of the hypothetical main clause**: *workers would wear respirators*.  Even so, the subjunctive mood is fading out of use, so you will encounter less confusion if you opt for:

> **In a perfect world**, workers would wear respirators even when
>   dust levels **are** low.

Comment: *without the relative clause would be very easy to construct:* <== Er, did you really mean to use the grammatical term *"relative clause"* in your post like that? (Aside: I'm not the down voter of your answer post.)

Comment: Thanks, @F.E. Must have been high dust levels in the brain.

Comment: There might be a reasonable interpretation where "when" could possibly be considered to be a relative word in a fused relative construction: *"workers would wear respirators even **when** dust levels were low"*, with the interpretation "workers would wear respirators even *at the times at which* dust levels were low". But one might not want to get into that kind of territory when one doesn't have too. :)

Comment: That's where I was intuitively, but it is a non-standard approach worth avoiding.